# Rename auto-generated UI header files in QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

This may seem like a bizarre request, but is there a way to change how Qt Creator names the auto-generated header files for the UI forms in your project?  The default naming convention is **ui_filename.h** for a ui file named **filename.ui**.  I want to change this to be **filename.ui.h** instead.

This is purely for backward compatibility.  I have a rather large project with lots of .ui files in it that I want to port from a Visual Studio project to a Qt Creator project.  In Visual Studio we used custom build scripts to generate header files for the forms using the convention filename.ui.h.  Not only would it be a pain to change all of the places in our code that includes those files, but it'd be a pain for others that we release our code to to also change theirs.

Comment: It's not the Qt creator doing it, but rather qmake. You'll have to check into qmake's logic (source code) and see if it's something configurable. There's a 50/50 chance of it being undocumented, though. If it's not configurable, you'll have to patch qmake.

Comment: Technically it's uic.exe which allows you to specify the output filename, but Qt Creator is the one calling it and I don't see anywhere that you can specify a custom output filename.

Comment: Qt Creator *does not* call `uic`! `make` does, and the commands are given in the `Makefile` that `qmake` generates. So yes, you *will* in fact need to coax `qmake` to do the emit the right invocation of uic. You don't need to mess with uic itself, nor make, nor Qt Creator. Qt Creator calls two things: `qmake` to generate the initial `Makefile`, and then `make` each subsequent time. That is *all*. When you press Ctrl-B, you launch `make` that acts on `qmake`'s previously-generated output (the `Makefile`). I repeat: whatever changes will be to the `.pro` file, and perhaps to `qmake` too.

Comment: @Moohasha: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, we ended up just changing our code to include u_filename.h. =\